# Surely there's a simple way to "bind" appended list items to an existing UL?

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists, bind

I can't believe I'm asking this, but can't find a clear answer about it.  My UL starts with two items in it, and is being further populated by way of an AJAX call.  I simply want to have the returned items appended to that UL, and have them "clickable" like the two that are already there.

I've seen a dozen different complicated, convoluted answers involving BIND, LIVE, DELEGATE, MAP - all with discussion about why the others should not be used.  While those dicussions all have value (I'm sure), none of them seem to give a clear answer about something as (seemingly) simple as this. Surely there is a straight forward method of appending an LI, and having it use the .click() event that has been defined for the list.

```
$.each(api, function(i,item) {
    var listItem = "<li meeting_id='" + item.meeting_id + "'>" + item.meeting_name + "</li>";
    $("#MeetingList").append(listItem);
    /*Do Something here to bind the newly appended LI to the existing click event */
}
```

Comment: can you show the way you bind the click for the first two elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (deprecated in favour of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery 1.7+) to have click handlers function for elements added to the dom *after* the even handler was bound. The code you posted for adding elements is fine. The code that needs to change is wherever you're binding your click handler.

Instead of

```
$('ul li').click(function () { ... });
```

You'll need to use

```
$('ul').delegate('li', 'click', function () { ... });
```

or, in jQuery 1.7+,

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () { ... });
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.. use `.on()`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli `on` only exists in jquery 1.7, there is nothing in the question that states the OP is using 1.7

Comment: @mattytommo, still `live` was superseded by `.delegate()` as of 1.4.2 So it still should not be used..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli but it wasn't *deprecated* like you said :). It was only deprecated in 1.7 (see http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: @mattytommo, indeed it was not deprecated before 1.7 but the `live` page states ***Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`***

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yep no complaints about that, but it wasn't *deprecated* until 1.7 :)

Comment: Oh My Dear God.....it really IS that simple....(I feel silly for not having understood it).  I've seen that over and over, but didn't understand the context of how to implement it.  I can't begin to thank you enough for having clear stated that answer in the context of the question.  I always appreciate the knowledge that comes with the advice of others, but so often get lost in the theory of the discussion that the answer becomes unclear.

Comment: @mattytommo, agreed.. the deprecated comment was in regards to 1.7 which i considered the OP to be using..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli fair enough, just gotta be careful as `on` didn't exist pre-1.7 :)

Comment: Even with this "convolusion", lol...at least there is clarity about HOW and for which version.  Again - thankyou, thankyou, thankyou.